# @types/async has no types for individual exports ex. async/each

Tags: typescript, async.js

TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'async/xxxx'. '/node_modules/async/xxxx.js' implicitly has an 'any' type

Running with noImplicitAny.
Not a listed issue on @types/async

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your project definition file one per export used:
`declare module 'xxxx';`

For exaple:
`declare module 'async/each';`

Source:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15031